# connect bluetooth shield with windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, sphero-api

i'm trying to listen for incomming bluetooth-connections from a bluetooth sheild to my WindowsPhone8 device. Is there any way to connect WindowsPhone8 with bluetooth sheild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the remote device supports Bluetooth Serial Port Protocol (BT-SPP) and supports pairing, you should be able to open a BT-SPP socket to it from WP8.

Here's a code sample of connecting to Sphero @ http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Bluetooth:_Phone_to_device

And here's a code sample of connecting to Mindwave Mobile Headset @ http://metroeeg.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Standalone&referringTitle=Home